# TFS proxy server configuration

Tags: tfs, tfs-proxy

We have a TFS Server on a different domain and we are trying to configure a TFS proxy on a different domain which connects through the Internet. What user account has to be provided when configuring the TFS proxy? If this needs to be the TFS server then we can't because its on another domain.

Answer (score 1):

ALthough its bit late..but it will be usefull for others.

You will need to do the following:

1. Create tfsproxy user in your domain.
2. Use this user account to run tfs proxy.
3. Create LOCAL user account at TFS Application tier(i.e. TFS Server) with exactly the same username and password of tfsproxy user created in step 1.
4. Give this local user account permission to your porject in TFS.

ref: [http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrniel/archive/2010/01/20/getting-tfs-source-control-proxy-working-in-a-workgroup-or-untrusted-domain.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20160722072419/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrniel/archive/2010/01/20/getting-tfs-source-control-proxy-working-in-a-workgroup-or-untrusted-domain.aspx) (archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160722072419/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chrniel/archive/2010/01/20/getting-tfs-source-control-proxy-working-in-a-workgroup-or-untrusted-domain.aspx)).